# Does Gauss's Lemma hold for odd composite numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

By Gauss's Lemma, I mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(number_theory)

If I allow $p$ to be any odd positive number rather than just a prime number, and still require that $a$ and $p$ be coprime, then does the Lemma still hold? We would use the Jacobi symbol rather than the Legendre symbol so we could handle composite numbers.

Comment: No, Gauss' lemma is based on the fact that $p$ is a prime number

Comment: See https://books.google.de/books?id=VYzqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=%22gauss+lemma%22+composite&source=bl&ots=QzH4x4xQSs&sig=ACfU3U2TiofbzQgBNEYgNeSjymJn7heDgw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiQtZTF_-biAhUNAxAIHRnOAbcQ6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22gauss%20lemma%22%20composite&f=false